# jquery autocomplete json won't display - css issue?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, display

I am trying to get a part number and description by autocompleting the partNumb id.

I get a PHP response for my autocomplete request:

```js
[{
"partNumb":"500406-12610532",
"partDesc":"Bray Series 50 ",
"vendName":"U",
"manuName":"Bray"
}]
```

I am using the simplest of AC requests:

```js
$('#partNumber_1').autocomplete(
{
   minLength:4,
   source: "db_AC.php?name=PN",
   dataType: "json"
});
```

The browser show two thin LIs, but nothing in them...

How can I have a label for partNumb and the part description in the description textfield?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As i can [see in the docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), your data need to respect the format supported for source: `[{label: "Choice1", value: "value1"}, ...]`

If you can't edit this response, you need to filter the data. I recommend you do an ajax to retrieve your data and put in a variable, then filter as below

```js
$(function() {
  //stored variable from ajax call
  var dataFromPhp = [{
    "partNumb": "500406-12610532",
    "partDesc": "Bray Series 50 ",
    "vendName": "U",
    "manuName": "Bray"
  }, {
    "partNumb": "500406-12610532",
    "partDesc": "Test Series 50 ",
    "vendName": "A",
    "manuName": "Allin"
  }];

  var filter = $.map(dataFromPhp, function(data, i) {
    return [{
      label: data.partDesc,
      value: data.partNumb
    }];
  });

  $('#partNumber_1').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: filter,
    //source: "db_AC.php?name=PN", USE THIS IN AJAX CALL
    //dataType: "json"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
  <label for="tags">Autocomplete: </label>
  <input id="partNumber_1">
</div>
```

Comment: This is convoluted - I have json returned from autocomplete response, can you help me format it to display correctly?

Comment: As I did above will solve, using map function to format the array of your response. All you need to do is replace the var `dataFromPhp` with one `ajax function` that return the data of your php code in `success`. Let me know if you can't do that.